# What is the longest word you can come up with that the letters are all in alphabetical order?

Tags: orthography

It's Friday again, how about some fun to get us into the weekend?

What is the longest word you can come up with for which all the letters in that word are in alphabetical order?

Rules:

- English words only
- Can't be a name of a place, person or other proper noun.
- if it contains the same letter twice in a row, that does not disqualify it.
- No fair looking it up on Google!

Update: One more rule to help you guys out.

- The word can be in either ascending or descending alphabetical order.

Comment: Maybe this should be community wiki?

Comment: @cthom06 - Right you are, corrected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, well another Friday, another Perl script. Here’s this week’s:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
my @alphas;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my @words = split /\s+/;
    foreach my $word (@words) {
        $word =~ s/[^A-Za-z]//g;
        next unless $word =~ /^[A-Za-z]{2,}$/;
        $word = uc $word;
        my @letters = split //, $word;
        my $sorted_word = join '', sort @letters;
        if ($sorted_word eq $word) {
            push @{$alphas[length $word]}, $word;
        }
    }
}

for (1..2) {
    print join "\n", @{pop @alphas};
    print "\n=====\n";

}
```

This time I used as the input corpus the AGID word list from [Kevin’s Word Lists](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/):

And got this output:

```
AEGILOPS
=====
BILLOWY
DIKKOPS
=====
```

[Aegilops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aegilops) (length 8) is a genus of grasses, and so is proper noun and might not count. *[Billowy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/billowy)* (length 7) is definitely a commonly-used, legit word. *Dikkops* (length 7), also known as [Stone-curlews](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dikkop), are a South African bird.

Comment: It can't have the same letter twice in a row.

Comment: @Arlen, the rules say “if it contains the same letter twice in a row, that does **not** disqualify it.” (emphasis mine)

Comment: nohat is correct, my intent that double letters in sequence still count as being in alphabetical order.

Comment: @nohat - I'm gonna have to remember the no Perl rule for next week. =)

Comment: I feel like I am on stackoverflow.com. `:-)`

Comment: @JohnFx: I would extend the rule to any programming language; I am sure nohat knows at least two scripting languages. `;-)`

Answer (score 8):

I **ALMOST** had it.

Answer (score 3):

Code golf and /usr/dict/words:

```
perl -nle '$x="^".join("*",("a".."z"))."*\$";if(/$x/){print length($_)," ",$_}' /usr/dict/words|sort -nr|head

8 aegilops
7 egilops
7 deglory
7 billowy
7 belloot
7 begorry
7 beefily
7 alloquy
6 knotty
6 knoppy
```

Answer (score 1):

I got **accent**

Comment: I'm pretty sure abcess is a misspelling of abscess.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've edited accordingly. I could also add 'begins'.

Answer (score 1):

If you had asked about vowels in order rather than letters, then two good ones would be facetiously and abstemiously.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can think of is "Oopsy!" which isn't exactly a dictionary word.