# Is there a name for a word where all the letters are in alphabetical order

Tags: single-word-requests, sort-ordering

After [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1509), is there a word for a word where all of its letters are in alphabetical order?

Examples of such words:

- AEGILOPS
- BILLOWY
- ALMOST

<sup><sub>(If the word in question is also one of those words, that would be incredible!)</sub></sup>

Comment: No, there isn't such a word.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can call them ***abecedarian words***.

Abecedarian is an adjective meaning "being arranged alphabetically". It comes from the Latin *abecedarius*, which means "alphabetical," based on the names of the first letters of the Latin alphabet.

For example, below are the terms mentioned in a personal site:

> **Abecedarian Words:** Words with letters in alphabetical order 
>  **Strictly Abecedarian Words:** Words with letters in alphabetical order without repetitions
>
> <sub>http://www.tanyakhovanova.com/</sub>

It is also mentioned in this stackoverflow question: 
[Counting abecedarian words in a list: Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967395/counting-abecedarian-words-in-a-list-python)

Comment: Note that *abecedarian* has some additional meanings, so beware of potential ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

There are  [fifty-three](https://www.wordnik.com/lists/words-with-letters-in-alphabetical-order) such words, but nobody seems to have coined a term for them.

some more examples: biopsy, abort, begin.