# Longest lexicographic English word?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What is the longest lexicographic English word?

In other words, what's the longest English word who's letters are in alphabetical order?

Comment: Interesting question. Now I'm curious, too :)

Comment: A simple Google search leads to the [Guinness World Book of Records](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/longest-english-word-with-letters-arranged-in-alphabetical-order/), which tells us it’s **aegilops**.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_word_in_English) suggests _Aegilops_ as well, but also argues against it as it is Latin and a proper noun. If you accept that argument, then there are a few six letters words: abhors, almost, begins, biopsy, chimps and chintz.

Comment: You could have a look [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1509/what-is-the-longest-word-you-can-come-up-with-that-the-letters-are-all-in-alphab?s=7|1.4307)

Comment: The _If-it-appears-anywhere-on-the-internet-it-must-be-called-a-word_ school doubtless has a 26-letter one.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I think I used to sing a song to my kids with that word in it.

Comment: @dave The Wikipedia article seems unaware that an aegilops (lowercase) is also a kind of stye (OED definition: “An abscess or ulcer of the inner canthus of the eye, esp. when involving a lacrimal duct or the lacrimal sac; (also) a lacrimal fistula”), in which case it is definitely not a proper noun. The two meanings are in fact probably etymologically unrelated: the former, ‘goatgrass’ is from _αἰγίλωψ_, possibly a corruption of _αἴγιλος_ ‘pertaining to goats’; the latter, ‘stye’, is from an identical _αἰγίλωψ_ which, however, is probably a corruption of _ἀγχίλωψ_ ‘something near/in the eye’.